# sonar design plugin unsatisfied dependency

Tags: sonarqube

I have recently upgraded to SonarQube 5.1.2 and have added the "design" plugin that I used to have in my old 3.2 instance.
This is my list of installed plugins:

```
cobertura,false,sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.6.3.jar|3ea2c0afe6e6b9701e4d5c8af382d388
emailnotifications,true,sonar-email-notifications-plugin-5.1.2.jar|3dd4e623752556c7a8757c1989af0ece
python,false,sonar-python-plugin-1.5.jar|268d44b47786147ef51376215c6c230a
crowd,false,sonar-crowd-plugin-2.0.jar|f580d366b948f01071317ef28bb60da1
pmd,false,sonar-pmd-plugin-2.4.1.jar|ff3781c9788d4e83f60e83bbd3d12e10
motionchart,false,sonar-motion-chart-plugin-1.7.jar|bdb198c2207ef033d6f1ee3e3eaea2b1
scmsvn,false,sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.0.jar|6915a69a7810c2b33ad4276d99a23077
javascript,false,sonar-javascript-plugin-2.8.jar|0f87170f4cec0f7fc51b6572530153f9
core,true,sonar-core-plugin-5.1.2.jar|b86ec05f4953608b2b4b697c027ab994
csharp,false,sonar-csharp-plugin-4.2.jar|af49378c5127353a2536ae77159ddbbb
buildstability,false,sonar-build-stability-plugin-1.3.jar|efc9f452c6fa20e268b6f1bb974d8e93
findbugs,false,sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.3.jar|f89994727607c7aacbea6e9396fed153
groovy,false,sonar-groovy-plugin-1.2.jar|14908dd5f3a9b9d795dbc103f0af546f
java,false,sonar-java-plugin-3.5.jar|64ff984b1b847bb6089cdda940ac0483
web,false,sonar-web-plugin-2.4.jar|1dbfc63768da3d753a61eda6146a8f7b
scmgit,false,sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.0.jar|e1d9d8e1d3524f9f0f69017e6dbead02
design,false,sonar-design-plugin-4.5.6.jar|6858390fab9e7e9e781bd17a837e32ce
scmstats,false,sonar-scm-stats-plugin-0.3.1.jar|79b6807b2bc2fe5d0607c37557ceb2be
timeline,false,sonar-timeline-plugin-1.5.jar|bbd6b21fb738281b5dd42e793d01bb5f
php,false,sonar-php-plugin-2.6.jar|5e37936c012cca253006867af1748793
l10nen,true,sonar-l10n-en-plugin-5.1.2.jar|bb21d03934050deec6cc95d0063d7789
checkstyle,false,sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.3.jar|9c90929f5f058f6372f0f2346ab0d3ed
jira,false,sonar-jira-plugin-1.2.jar|0e68329678d4706d2d98e0f08fd5306e
```

I'm getting this error while trying to run mvn clean verify sonar:sonar on a project that used to work with old Sonar version. 
It also works OK when I exclude that design plugin:

```
-Dsonar.excudePlugins=design
```

Any idea on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project myproject: org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.MavenDependenciesSensor has unsatisfied dependency 'interface org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeBuilder' for constructor 'public org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.MavenDependenciesSensor(org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository,org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.ArtifactFactory,org.apache.maven.artifact.metadata.ArtifactMetadataSource,org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactCollector,org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeBuilder,org.sonar.api.batch.SonarIndex)' from org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@232af575:310<[Immutable]:org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@5177d2af:252<[Immutable]:org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@4f265869:23<[Immutable]:org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@6760353c:107<| -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project myproject: org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.MavenDependenciesSensor has unsatisfied dependency 'interface org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeBuilder' for constructor 'public org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.MavenDependenciesSensor(org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository,org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.ArtifactFactory,org.apache.maven.artifact.metadata.ArtifactMetadataSource,org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactCollector,org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeBuilder,org.sonar.api.batch.SonarIndex)' from org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@232af575:310<[Immutable]:org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@5177d2af:252<[Immutable]:org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@4f265869:23<[Immutable]:org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@6760353c:107<|
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.MavenDependenciesSensor has unsatisfied dependency 'interface org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeBuilder' for constructor 'public org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.MavenDependenciesSensor(org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository,org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.ArtifactFactory,org.apache.maven.artifact.metadata.ArtifactMetadataSource,org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactCollector,org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeBuilder,org.sonar.api.batch.SonarIndex)' from org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@232af575:310<[Immutable]:org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@5177d2af:252<[Immutable]:org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@4f265869:23<[Immutable]:org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@6760353c:107<|
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Is your design plugin compatible with SonarQube 5.2 APIs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now the last available version of the SonarQube Design Plugin is [4.5.6](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.codehaus.sonar.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22sonar-design-plugin%22).

Plugin `pom.xml` file contains text

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.6</version>
    <relativePath>../..</relativePath>
</parent>
```

which mean that this plugin is compatible with SonarQube 4.5.6 LTS. So unfortunately you cannot use this plugin with SonarQube 5.2.